# How to ensure an element in view when a webpage is opened?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

What are some effective strategies to ensure a specific control is in view when a page is opened?

More specifically, I have a validation message which appears beneath the fold, and I want to ensure it is seen when necessary.

I considered using a bookmark (named anchor) but there is no clean way to use it, since I only realize there is an error after I've processed the page.

This won't matter with most expected solutions, but I'm adding the asp.net-mvc tag, in case there is anything funky in the framework that might help me.

And yes, jQuery solutions are ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Answered on Twitter](http://twitter.com/#!/wolever/status/10431794335719425) by [David Wolever](http://twitter.com/#!/wolever)

```
document.onload = function() { location.href = "#foo" }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the scrollIntoView call in Javascript to do this - it will give you roughly the same result as an anchor, but you can do the call specifically when you need to scroll the error into view.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use jquery to do it, like so:

```
 window.scrollTo(
     $("#wannaBeVisible").position().left, 
     $("#wannaBeVisible").position().top);
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a usability problem that you are trying to solve with code. The validation message should be closer to the control in question or else they won't seem related.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way: Create an anchor tag next to your control, give it a name and load file.html#anchorname.

If changing the url is not possible, you can call focus on an anchor element and that will scroll it into view

Answer (score 0):

Markup your validation message something like this;

```
<p class="validation">Validation message here!</p>
```

And then position it with CSS something like this;

```
.validation {
display: block;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 1.5em;
}
```

You'll probably have to experiment with some variation of that, but it should be a good place to start. This will do something similar to the notifications that pop up on the top of Stack Overflow, except they will be at the bottom of the window.

No JS required!

[More information on CSS Fixed Positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

Comment: I'm trying to stay consistent with the other validation messages in the app, so I can't do this. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Also, did you vote down everybody but yourself?  Cause it definitely looks that way.  Not cool.

Comment: You could display the validation message as usual, and add a notification that is displayed as above. Or, you could use the anchor method that you described, but load the page with the validation area in view, whether it contains messages or not.

Comment: And I voted down methods that require JS. There is no reason to use JS when it is not required and doing so makes web pages in general less accessible.

Comment: I tend to agree with you about js (although lately I've changed my position), but since my question implies that js is ok, I don't know if a down vote is appropriate. KWIM?  .... but thanks for your answer though.

Comment: Sorry, I voted you down because IE6 doesn't accept the "fixed" property.

Comment: Upvote, 10 rep.  Downvote, 2 rep.  Honestly, its not worth worrying about.  The system takes care of egregious vote gaming; this probably wouldn't qualify.